# Pilots use of the term "with" then a letter when talking to ground

Tags: air-traffic-control, terminology, taxiing

In ground comms when taxiing a pilot may say for example:

"Kennedy ground, DELTA412 HEAVY, is in KILO-FOX, short of ALPHA **with PAPA**".

I get that this means they waiting a KF exit of the ramp just sort of the A taxiway but what does "with PAPA" phrase mean?

Comment: @Bianfable thanks I get it, "with" is simple shortening of the phrase "with information" and that refers to the ATIS information version they are working with.

Comment: Yes, the [AIM 4-2-3 a. Initial Contact 3.](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap4_section_2.html) says to use the following phraseology: “(ATIS) Information Charlie received”, but it is usually shortened to "with Charlie". (assuming US regulations, since your quote is from JFK)

Comment: By the way, this isn't just used when talking to ground, it's also used on initial contact with approach or tower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that was the exact phraseology, "papa" is the latest ATIS they've copied. (ATIS being a continuous broadcast of recorded aeronautical information, updated every half hour, or in case of a major change).

Listen to arrival ATIS [Heathrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnpE5NM1W68), and, at the very end, note the instruction to inform Heathrow on first contact.
Similarly, here's departure ATIS at JFK with similar instruction in the last line:

> KJFK JFK ATIS INFO F 0251Z. 32004KT 10SM SCT140 BKN170 27/22 A3012
> (THREE ZERO ONE TWO). APPROACH IN USE ILS RY 4R, RNAV Y RY 4L. DEPG RY
> 4L. NOTAMS... ILS RWY 22R OTS, RY 4L GS OTS. HAZD WX INFO FOR NY METRO
> AREA AVBL ON FSS. SWAP IN EFFECT EXPECT REROUTES. BIRD ACTIVITY
> VICINITY ARPT. NUM CRANES OPERATING AT JFK. READBACK ALL RWY HOLD
> SHORT INSTRUCTIONS. ...ADVS YOU HAVE INFO F.

Answer (score 2):

More related information about ATIS:

ATIS is renewed periodically, and "named" sequentially with ICAO alphabet (alfa, bravo, charlie etc.).

The reason for informing ATC which ATIS you have copied is that sometimes the ATIS changes after pilot has received it , and changes may contain useful information for pilot (in the question pilot had listened to ATIS named *papa*). ATC would then inform the pilot that "Current information is *quebec*". This would (should) prompt the pilot to listen to ATIS again.